# How do you pass validation errors across controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm making a conventional forum in Rails to practice. I have a `Topic` model and a nested `Post` model. Topics can have many Posts.

`Topics#Show` has a list of `@topic.posts` and then a new Post form.

```
# Topics#Show
def show
  @topic = Topic.find(params[:id])
  @post = @topic.posts.new
end
```

Submitting a new post sends it to `Posts#Create`

```
# Posts#Create
  def create
    @topic = Topic.find(params[:topic_id])
    @post = @topic.posts.new(params[:post])
    @post.user = current_user
    if @post.save
      redirect_to @topic, :notice => "Successfully created post."
    else
      render :action => 'new' # <-- Unsure what to do here
    end
  end
```

If the Post fails to save, I want it to render `Topics#Show` and display the validation errors there.

From what I understand, params don't persist through a `redirect_to` because a 302 redirect starts a new request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should render the topics/show view. So instead of

```
render :action => 'new' # <-- Unsure what to do here
```

Do:

```
render :template => 'topics/show'
```

Comment: In the topics#show view, I render the post form with `<%= render 'post_form' %>` which is the partial `topics/_post_form.erb`. So when I submit a post form from topics#show with validation problems, it gives me the error: `Missing partial posts/post_form`

Comment: Ah, I moved `topics/_post_form.erb` to `posts/_form.erb` and made `topics#show` render `posts/form` instead.

My url changes from `topics/2` to `topics/2/posts` when I submit my form. I don't have a posts index. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Why do you want to change that?

Comment: The Post model only exists to be displayed on Topic views. The topic#show action (`/topics/2`) IS the index of posts, for my intents. In other words, I don't ever use Posts#Index.

Comment: You don't need the index action, because you are doing a POST request and not a GET request. What you are doing now should work fine. If you are afraid of people bookmarking the wrong URL you could add Posts#index and redirect to the topic.

Comment: Do you know why Rails would append `/posts` to `/topics/2` when I submit the posts form from topics#show and validation fails?

Comment: This is how Rails is designed. If you want to know more about the backgrounds of this google for 'restful resources' or have a look at this page: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html. Basically when you do a POST request to `/topics/2/posts` Rails knows it has to execute Posts#create.

Comment: Rails doesn't append `/posts` to `/topics/2`. The form is submitted to `/topics/2/posts`. If there are no errors you are redirected back to `/topics/2`. If there are errors you stay at `/topics/2/posts` and render a view to show the errors.

Comment: Oh, duh. That's because Rails is sending the request to the Posts controller. I guess I can live with `/posts/` popping up only when there's a validation error. Thanks for the help! You got more than you bargained for! :)

Answer (score 1):

Use `render :template => "topics/show"` and be sure to set up the `@topic` variable identically to how you do it in the `TopicsController#show` action. You will not be able to call this `show` method from the `PostsController` though.